# Filter data in redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I create record in redis using

```
var data = { 'userid': 'user1' ,  'message': 'test message' };   
redisClient.hmset('messages:' + 1 , data);

var data1 = { 'userid': 'user2' ,  'message': 'test message' };   
redisClient.hmset('messages:' + 2 , data1);
```

I want to get data from messages by userid = user2.. how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *filter* directly. You should do this by using different keys by `userid`:

```
var data1 = { "userid": "user1" ,  "message': "test message" };   
redisClient.hmset("messages:" + data1.userid , data1.message);

var data2 = { "userid": "user2" ,  "message': "test message" };   
redisClient.hmset("messages:" + data2.userid , data2.message);
```

You can then use

```
redisClient.hgetall("messages:user1")
```

to get all messages from `user1`.

If you want to partition by timestamp (which is not in your original question), you'll have to use a *Sorted Set* instead of a *Hash*:

```
redisClient.zadd("messages:" + data1.userid, new Date().getTime(), data1.message);
```

Use

```
redisClient.zrange("messages:" + data1.userid, 0, -1);
```

to receive the messages sorted by timestamp.

Comment: if i change var data2 = { "userid": "user2" ,  "message': "test message" , "userid to" : "any user id"};
i want to filter all message from user2 send to user3 or user4

Comment: i edited my comment

if i change var data2 = { "userid": "user2" , "message': "test message" , "userid to" : "any user id"}; i want to filter all message from user2 send to user3 or user4 – how do this

Comment: Have you read my answer? I don't think so... You need to use different keys, one per user, as I wrote.

Comment: yes, i has read your ans, i want to use redis to storage all chat message, i want use time() is key

Comment: example var data2 = { id: date(),  "user_from": "user2" ,  "message': "test message", "user_to":"any user id"  };   how to filter data by user from and user to

Comment: Dang, it's in my answer! Use `redisClient.hgetall("messages:user1")` to get all messages from `user1`!